# Iscroll is slow and doesnt move smooth when there are 30+ items in it

Tags: javascript, iscroll4

When I have more items ( like 30 ) in my iscroll my iscroll plugin on mobile becomes really slow ( I think its because there are some unnecessary paints or is my mobile phone to slow ?) and it doesnt move smooth.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/unnecessary-paints/
Do you have any suggestions for another plugin or how to fix this ?

im using handelbars to render it. but the html structure looks like this :

```
<div id="notificationsScroll">
    <div id="notificationList" class="friends-tiles">
      <div class="smooth friend">

       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css looks like this

```
#notificationsScroll{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width: auto;/* your desired width, auto and 100% are fine */;
    height: 73%;
    //height: 334px;/* element height */;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Im using iScroll v4.1.6

Comment: What phone are you using? In my experience iScroll works very efficiently even with hundreds of rows with graphical content. I would guess that there may be an issue with your implementation...can you post some code? Check also that you're using iScroll4 and not iScroll3.

Comment: ...moving comment to an answer to show code better...!

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippets don't show that you've applied iScroll - that may be an oversight in pasting the code, or that could be the problem...iscroll overrides the native scrolling which historically was slow and unintuitive in a touch interface (on iPhone at least!).  Are you initialising iScroll in JS?

```
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('notificationsScroll');
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

Comment: yep im initialising iScroll i just didnt put that in this code snippet. Iscroll works great on galaxy s2, s3, iphone. But it isnt smooth at all on androind 2.3

Comment: OK, it must be an issue specific to Android - Googling 'iscroll slow on android' comes up with various discussions about this, some offer workarounds, but I haven't seen any definitive fixes :(